# android clear arraylist or adapter?

Tags: android, arraylist, adapter, android-arrayadapter

After working on an app for a while I realize I use

```
adapter.clear()
and 
arraylist.clear()
```

I can see both are working just fine, I would like to know the difference between the two!

Both are called before I start and asyncTask that updates my list with information from my server!

Comment: Are you using ArrayAdapter? If you call ArrayAdapter#clear(), you don't need to call notifyDataSetChanged, because it will be called automatically. If you use arrayList.clear(), you will need to call notifyDataSetChanged by yourself.

Comment: I am using arrayAdapter, and the notifyDataSetChanged in those places.

put in other places I have used the ArrayAdapter.clear (and dont use the notifyDataSetChanged)

but I wonder if one is preferred over the other!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not be clearing the `ArrayList` directly. The `ArrayAdapter` makes absolutely no guarantees that it maintains the same referenced list given to it.  In fact it will change when you perform a search with it's filter.  Which would make `arrayList.clear()` fail.

Rule of thumb, if you ever need to mutate or retrieve the associating data...do it directly from the adapter.  Not the list you used to construct it.

Comment: I am working on Adapter section for a RecyclerView and just came across your answer.  I would appreciate it if you could weigh in on my problem because it specifically has an ArrayList.clear() that you warn against, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41969397/android-how-do-i-maintain-the-view-for-cardviews-in-a-recyclerview-list

Answer (score 0):

Adapter = it contains copies of diff views,arrays

aaraylist holds the data which we want to display in our view.

ex: `arraylist<HashMap<String,String>> ah= new  ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();`

the above list contains hashmap

if i clear the arraylist there will be no data to show on listview or gridview so it will be empty

if i clear adapter than it will destroy the copies of array and views so the output will be same